# In Notepad++ find dash + end of line and merge the two lines

Tags: notepad++

I have the following text:

```
вече не делят човечеството на отделни затворени общности. Човеш-
кото общество не е толкова разединено, колкото в Средновековието;
налице е тенденция към образуването на единна държава, на единна
човешка общност. Според Шрӣмад Бхагаватам идеалите на духов-
ния комунизъм се основават в една или друга степен на единството
на човечеството, нещо повече, на единството от енергията на всич-
ки живи същества. Великите мислители са разбирали необходимостта
```

and what I am trying to achieve is to remove all the dashes (-) and merge the current line with the next one so that we can have the following end result:

```
вече не делят човечеството на отделни затворени общности. Човешкото общество не е толкова разединено, колкото в Средновековието;
налице е тенденция към образуването на единна държава, на единна
човешка общност. Според Шрӣмад Бхагаватам идеалите на духовния комунизъм се основават в една или друга степен на единството
на човечеството, нещо повече, на единството от енергията на всички живи същества. Великите мислители са разбирали необходимостта
```

What I have tried so far is the following (within Notepad++ installed on Windows 11):

```
\r?(-)\n
```

https://regex101.com/r/LmhtSS/1

but is not working in Notepad++

Here is another try:

- `Ctrl`+`H`
- Find what: `-$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- check Wrap around
- check Regular expression
- Replace all

and the result is:

```
вече не делят човечеството на отделни затворени общности. Човеш
кото общество не е толкова разединено, колкото в Средновековието;
налице е тенденция към образуването на единна държава, на единна
човешка общност. Според Шрӣмад Бхгаватам идеалите на духов
ния комунизъм се основават в една или друга степен на единството
на човечеството, нещо повече, на единството от енергията на всич
ки живи същества. Великите мислители са разбирали необходимостта
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am trying to remove all the dashes (-) and merge the current line with the next one

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `-\R`
- Set "Replace with" to `empty string`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

[image]

**Before**:

вече не делят човечеството на отделни затворени общности. Човеш-
кото общество не е толкова разединено, колкото в Средновековието;
налице е тенденция към образуването на единна държава, на единна
човешка общност. Според Шрӣмад Бхагаватам идеалите на духов-
ния комунизъм се основават в една или друга степен на единството
на човечеството, нещо повече, на единството от енергията на всич-
ки живи същества. Великите мислители са разбирали необходимостта

**After**:

вече не делят човечеството на отделни затворени общности. Човешкото общество не е толкова разединено, колкото в Средновековието;
налице е тенденция към образуването на единна държава, на единна
човешка общност. Според Шрӣмад Бхагаватам идеалите на духовния комунизъм се основават в една или друга степен на единството
на човечеството, нещо повече, на единството от енергията на всички живи същества. Великите мислители са разбирали необходимостта

Note:

> `\R` ⇒ Any newline sequence. Specifically, the atomic group `(?>\r\n|\n|\x0B|\f|\r|\x85|\x{2028}|\x{2029})`. Please note, this sequence might match one or two characters, depending on the text. Because its length is variable-width, it cannot be used in lookbehinds. Because it expands to a parentheses-based group with an alternation sequence, it cannot be used inside a character class. If you accidentally attempt to put it in a character class, it will be interpreted like any other literal-character escape (where \☒ is used to make sure that the next character is literal) meaning that the R will be taken as a literal R, without any special meaning. For example, if you try `[\t\R]`, you may be intending to say, “match any single character that’s a tab or a newline”, but what you are actually saying is “match the tab or a literal R”; to get what you probably intended, use `[\t\v]` for “a tab or any vertical spacing character”, or `[\t\r\n]` for “a tab or carriage return or newline but not any of the weird verticals”.

Source: [Searching | Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#regular-expressions)

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation?](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Your end of line type depends on the file and the system it was created on (you can see more specifically my showing all characters or only end of like, ***Menu Bar*** » ***View*** » Show ***symbol*** » ***Show end of line***.)

Try to find:

> -\r\n